# white space control in jekyll - why does {%- ... -%} a la liquid not work?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

The [liquid documentation](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/basics/whitespace) states that

> By including hyphens in your assign tag, you can strip the generated whitespace from the rendered template ... if you don't want any of your tags to output whitespace, as a general rule you can add hyphens to both sides of all your tags ({%- and -%}):

When I try in jekyll

```
{%- case key -%}
```

I get the error

```
Error: Liquid syntax error (line 139): Tag '{%- case key -%}' was not
properly terminated with regexp: /\%\}/
```

There are many posts about excessive whitespace in the jekyll generated html, for example [Compressing Liquid generated code](https://www.sylvaindurand.org/compressing-liquid-generated-html/).

They all complain about dilute HTML output and discuss plug-ins as solution.
My simple questions are:

1. Why does `{%- ... -%}` not work in jekyll ?
2. Why behaves jekyll differently than the liquid documentation suggests

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Jekyll < v3.5.0 use liquid v3.0.6.
White space control is only available in liquid v4 and this version will soon land in Jekyll.

As of 18 June 2017, [Jekyll v3.5.0](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/releases/tag/v3.5.0) has upgraded to Liquid v4. `{%- ... -%}` now works.

Comment: Thanks David, one simple answer for both questions !

Comment: Another comment: these days code is well versioned, but the documentation very often is not. This way one quickly gets this kind of disconnects. Liquid is a case in point. When I read in GitHub the [README.md](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/tree/8d19fdde7f48347107632f91efb84526aa4972c4) of [release v3.0.6](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/releases/tag/v3.0.6), it points to ["Liquid documentation from Shopify"](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/basics) which describes the current, thus v4.x, version.

Comment: Question remains how "soon" soon is.

Comment: @Marian I think it's a hard work to bring a new version to the public. Sometimes it's fast, sometimes it's slower. I hope we will have good surprises.

Comment: It looks like [this is the issue to watch on GitHub](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/6074).